# How to store JSON in mysql laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

So, i'm trying to store data in database as JSON, i've seen the built-in notification table doing that.

I created a field of type "text" and i'm storing this (example)

```
{"filenames":["D0BmpFOdyUp4YyA8tqpL60VxO9kXsfciP9eLhIxd.jpeg","nAAs1xeErQSxPGxPvP68bCMn4a0E3y4EcgwfCwJl.png"],"title":"asdasdasa","content":"adasdasa"}
```

It returns me string as expected, how do i make it understand as an array?

Do i have to add something in the model or...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) in Laravel's documentation. In your Eloquent model class, add a `$casts` property, for example:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'your_column_name' => 'array'
];
```

From Laravel Docs:

> The `$casts` property on your model provides a convenient method of converting attributes to common data types. The `$casts` property should be an array where the key is the name of the attribute being cast and the value is the type you wish to cast the column to.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for that for hours.